# Segmentation fault (core dumped) and zlib

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am very new to both using Linux and creating anything remotely serious on C. I've been trying to create a program which will simply compress a single string, but I keep getting this Segmentation fault when trying to run the compiled file.
I compiled it using:

```
gcc 2.c -o test.o -lz
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main ()
{
char *istream = malloc(10), *ostream = malloc(120);
istream = "istream";
int res = compress(ostream, (uLongf *)strlen(ostream), istream,(ulong)strlen(istream));
return 0;
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why this error is happening and how can I improve my code?

Comment: Why `C++`tag is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line would appear to be the main problem:

```
(uLongf*)strlen(ostream)
```

You are interpreting a `size_t` value as a pointer to a buffer. You are meant to pass the address of an `unsigned long` containing the length of the output buffer. Take another look at the documentation for `compress`.

On top of that you don't yet understand how C strings work. The assignment operator when used with a `char*` lvalue merely copies an address and not the contents of a string. I suggest that you declare your buffers like this:

```
const char *istream = "istream";
char ostream[120];
```

I think your program should be something along these lines:

```
int main(void)
{
    const char *istream = "istream";
    char ostream[120];
    uLongf destLen = sizeof(ostream);
    int res = compress((Bytef*)ostream, &destLen, (Bytef*)istream, strlen(istream));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I wrote the code assuming that you are using a C compiler. And hence `int main(void)`.

Comment: That parameter will be the actual size of the output after compression when the function returns, so it's an "output" parameter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's both input and output. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First you make `istream` point to memory you allocate:

```
char *istream = malloc(10)
```

***then*** you make it point to a literal (and therefore constant and read-only) string:

```
istream = "istream";
```

You need to *copy* the string literal into the allocated memory, or you will no longer have the original pointer you allocated and have a memory leak. You also will not be able to `free` that pointer, since `istream` points to something you haven't allocated with `malloc`.

As for the crash, see the answer by David Heffernan.

---

As a side-note, there is no C++ in your code, only pure and plain C.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
istream = "istream"
```

To

```
strcpy(istream,"istream");
```

In addition, what did you expect `strlen(ostream)` to return? 120?

`strlen` returns the index of the first 0 character encountered within the input string.

In your case, the contents of the memory pointed by `ostream` is unknown (i.e. "junk").

`strlen` will scan this memory until a 0 character is encountered, but will probably exceed the 120-byte memory space and cause a memory access violation.

Change `strlen(ostream)` to 120 if that was your intention.

Comment: Tried both this and sprintf(istream, "istream"), still gives segmentation error.

Comment: Well, assuming the segfault exception occurs when you call `compress`, why don't you publish this function as part of your question?

Comment: Hang on a second! Calling `strlen(ostream)` is the reason for the exception. What value did you expect this to return? 120? `strlern` returns the index of the first occurrence of a 0 character within the input string.